# EF Lambda for SQL : How to get a new column based on some string presence in other column of the same table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda

I want SQL query equivalent in EF Core Lambda, to get an extra column as either true or false, based on some substring(in this case ***DEALER***) if present in other column's data of the same table.

```
myTable
     Id                        col1
     1              I have substring - DEALER
     2              I do not have any substring
```

I need the output as

```
Id,                IsDealer
1,                  true   
2,                  false
```

I tried the following SQL query,

```
SELECT [Id] , 
CASE WHEN [col1] LIKE '%DEALER%' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as IsDealer 
FROM [dbo].[myTable]
```

I get proper output, But what is the above **SQL** query **EF CORE equivalent** ?

I tried

```
_Context.myTable.Where(et => et)
                        .Select(s => new myTableEFCoreModel
                         {
                             Id = s.Id,
                            **<what goes here for IsDealer>**
                        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the string in col1 so just doing a string compare should be all you need:

```
_Context.myTable.Where(et => et)
    .Select(s => new myTableEFCoreModel
    {
        /* same as select [Id] in sql query */
        Id = s.Id, 
        /* same as case when [col1] like "%DEALER%" then 'true' else 'false' as IsDealer */
        IsDealer = s.col1.Contains("DEALER") 
     });
```

Comment: sorry, I am not returing col1, i corrected the question. Is there a way without returning col1 to get IsDealer column correctly.

Comment: The suggestion is to simply replace `**<what goes here for IsDealer>**` with `IsDealer = s.col1.Contains("DEALER")`  You're not "returning" col1, you're using it in an expression in the query.  The expression will be translated to SQL and executed on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like IsDealer = s.col1.Contains("TextYouWantToSearch")

Comment: yes, it is something similar as the answer provided by @ProdigalTechie

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).